# How can I fix this type error in my code (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell
I have a task:
Write a trans N S function that simplifies the structure of an accounting expression S, replacing all list items at the N level [N> = 1], to the # character. For example: trans 2 [[[A,[5],8],B,[K]],[G, [C]]]] => [[# B #] [G #]]

Taking into account the fair remark that the list items in Haskell should be of the same type, I tried to switch to working with tree structure:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node [Tree a] deriving (Show)

trans :: Int -> Tree (Either Char [Int]) -> Tree (Either Char [Int])
trans _ (Leaf x) = Leaf x
trans 1 _ = Leaf '#'
trans n (Node children) = Node (map (trans (n-1)) children)

exampleTree :: Tree (Either Char [Int])
exampleTree = Node [Node [Node [Leaf (Left 'A'),Leaf (Right [5]),Leaf (Right [8])], Leaf (Left 'B'), [Leaf (Left 'K')]], Node [Leaf (Left 'G'), [Leaf (Left 'C')]]]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Original tree:"
  print exampleTree
  putStrLn "\nTransformed tree (transTree 1):"
  print $ trans 1 exampleTree
```

And, well, erors:

````
app/Main.hs:19:18: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Either Char [Int]’
                  with actual type ‘Char’
    • In the first argument of ‘Leaf’, namely ‘'#'’
      In the expression: Leaf '#'
      In an equation for ‘trans’: trans 1 _ = Leaf '#'
   |
19 | trans 1 _ = Leaf '#'
   |                  ^^^

app/Main.hs:23:102: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: Tree (Either Char [Int])
                  with actual type: [Tree (Either Char b0)]
    • In the expression: [Leaf (Left 'K')]
      In the first argument of ‘Node’, namely
        ‘[Node [Leaf (Left 'A'), Leaf (Right [...]), ....],
          Leaf (Left 'B'), [Leaf (Left 'K')]]’
      In the expression:
        Node
          [Node [Leaf (Left 'A'), Leaf (Right [...]), ....], Leaf (Left 'B'),
           [Leaf (Left 'K')]]
   |
23 | exampleTree = Node [Node [Node [Leaf (Left 'A'),Leaf (Right [5]),Leaf (Right [8])], Leaf (Left 'B'), [Leaf (Left 'K')]], Node [Leaf (Left 'G'), [Leaf (Left 'C')]]]
   |                                                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

app/Main.hs:23:145: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: Tree (Either Char [Int])
                  with actual type: [Tree (Either Char b1)]
    • In the expression: [Leaf (Left 'C')]
      In the first argument of ‘Node’, namely
        ‘[Leaf (Left 'G'), [Leaf (Left 'C')]]’
      In the expression: Node [Leaf (Left 'G'), [Leaf (Left 'C')]]
   |
23 | exampleTree = Node [Node [Node [Leaf (Left 'A'),Leaf (Right [5]),Leaf (Right [8])], Leaf (Left 'B'), [Leaf (Left 'K')]], Node [Leaf (Left 'G'), [Leaf (Left 'C')]]]```

Start to feel myself a little stupid, if be honest
````

Comment: Polymorphic lists do not work that way. The type [a] means a list of elements of any type a, but all the elements MUST be of the same type.

Your list "input" have element with inconsistent types : some elements  are characters and others are integers.

Comment: Standard Haskell lists can not represent your example `[[['A',[5],8],'B',['K']],['G',['C']]]`. For that, one would need to use a tree-like structure instead. Where did you find this exercise? Was it meant to be solved in Haskell? If so, perhaps who wrote the exercise expects you to use some special tree type (or to define one)?

Comment: @chi This assignment is from my professor, as one of the initial works in the study of Haskell...

Comment: `trans 1 _ = Leaf (Left '#')`. But it might actually make sense to have separate `Leaf` constructors for the `Char` and `[Int]` case, then you wouldn't need to use `Either` for that distinction.

Comment: I.e. `data AccountEx a = AccSym Char | AccQty a | AccBranches [AccountEx a]` or something like that.